# Freezing a frittata

Tags: eggs, freezing, frittata

I'm hoping to make a frittata to  last a few days to take to work for lunch.  Am I able to freeze it, if so are there any ingredients that do not freeze well and I should avoid putting in the frittata?

If they don't freeze well, how long do they typically keep well in a fridge?

Thanks.

Comment: For the fridge part, please see our generic question: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21068/how-long-can-i-store-a-food-in-the-pantry-refrigerator-or-freezer Even as an experienced SE user let me point you to our [help] for more information about this specific site and if you take the [tour], you'll even get a badge... Welcome to Seasoned Advice!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Frittata freezes just fine. At least, mine do. There are a couple of drawbacks you might want to take into account when making your recipe, though.

One is that the individual tastes of the ingredients all meld together when the frittata gets thawed or reheated, so if you're looking forward to that bite that has a particularly strong taste of, say, asparagus, it's not going to happen. Conversely, if you're looking forward to that bite that doesn't include the taste of green pepper, that's not going to happen, either, if you put it in there. I never use green pepper in frittata; it completely takes over the dish.

The other drawback is that some of the moister ingredients will lose water upon thawing or reheating, thus soaking the frittata on the second go-around and giving it an unpleasant, rubbery texture. If you plan to freeze your frittata, consider your ingredients with that in mind, and choose ones that are low-moisture (extra cheese, dried ham, etc.) or pre-cooked to cook out some of the moisture (mushrooms, sweet onion, etc.)